# Prove that $\sin x+\binom n1\sin {2x}+\binom n2\sin {3x} +...+\binom nn\sin {(n+1)x}=2^n.\cos^n \frac x2.\sin (\frac {n+2}2)x$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $$\sin x+\binom n1\sin {2x}+\binom n2\sin {3x} +...+\binom nn\sin {(n+1)x}=2^n.\cos^n \frac x2.\sin (\frac {n+2}2)x$$
I could think of only the fact that there has to be some kind of binomial expansion taking place so that the combinatorial coefficients come into place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to notice that this is the imaginary part of 
$$e^{ix} [ 1 + \binom n1 e^{ix} + \cdots + \binom nn e^{i(nx)} ] = e^{ix}(1+e^{ix})^n = e^{ix}(2\cos (x/2) e^{i(x/2)})^n$$ 
So our answer is the imaginary part of this, which is
$$\boxed{2^n \cos^n(x/2) \sin(\frac{n+2}{2})}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x+\binom n1\sin {2x}+\binom n2\sin {3x} +...+\binom nn\sin {(n+1)x}=?$$
We have that $$\sin(mx)=\frac{e^{imx}-e^{-imx}}{2i}$$So the sum above can be written as $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{m=1}^n\binom nm\left(e^{ix}(e^{ix})^m-e^{-ix}(e^{-ix})^m\right)&=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}(e^{ix}+1)^n-e^{-ix}(e^{-ix}+1)^n)\\&=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}e^{inx/2}2^n\cos^n(x/2)-e^{-ix}e^{-inx/2}2^n\cos^n(x/2))\\&=2^n\cdot\frac{1}{2i}\cos^n(x/2)\cdot(e^{i(\frac n2+1)x}-e^{-i(\frac  n2+1)x})\\&=2^n\cos^n(x/2)\sin\left(\left(\frac n2+1\right)x\right)\end{align}$$